# Unable to add custom claim in Tymon JWT

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm using **Tymon JWT** to generate my token in Laravel. I have followed the guide in [Tymon's github site](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens) carefully to add my custom claims like so:

```
$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];
JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims);
```

I managed to generate a token after authenticating the user, but when I decode the token with JWT decoder, I only see the default claims, but not  my custom claim.

Comment: Did you try and `var_dump` the results of `JWTAuth::attempt`?

Answer (score 7):

You are using **Tymon JWT** version 1.0.0 maybe?

From Github **Tymon JWT**

> For version 0.5.* See the [WIKI](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt) for documentation.
>
> Documentation for 1.0.0 is coming soon, but there is an unfinished guide [here](http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation)

Use

```
JWTAuth::customClaims(['foo' => 'bar'])->attempt(['login' => '', 'password' => '']);
```

Comment: I believe in rc2, custom claims must be implemented via the JWTSubject interface in the User model... http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/

Answer (score 2):

You can using:

```
$store = [
    'id'    => 1,
    'name'  => 'Store1'
];

$token = JWTAuth::customClaims(['store' => $store])->fromUser($user);
```

And get info:

```
$storeData = JWTAuth::getPayload()->get('store');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add custom claims by putting them the **getJWTCustomClaims** method on my **JWTSubject**.

Example: if you want to specify a guard for your user class and put that information inside the token, you do the following :

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [
            'guard' => 'admins', // my custom claim, add as many as you like
        ];
    }
}
```

Be aware not to add too many custom claims because they will increase the size of the token.

Here is the version of Tymon-jwt that i use : **"tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop#f72b8eb as 1.0.0-rc.3.2"**

Hope this helps